# Dúvida com referência ao usar add no LinkedList, java

Tags: java

Tenho um `LinkedList<CasosPossiveis> casos = new LinkedList<>();` e um `CasosPossiveis objeto = new CasosPossiveis();`. 
Dentro de um `for`, após essa declaração, faço um: `casos.add(objeto);`, após modificar os dados de objeto. Entretanto, o que acontece é que quando eu printo meu `casos`, os valores em todas as posições da lista estão iguais porque, ao que parece, `objeto`foi passado como referência no `casos.add(objeto);`. 
O que eu quero fazer é que, a cada vez que eu dar um `.add(objeto)`, um novo valor seja adicionado e não modificado mais, caso eu modifique o `objeto`. 
Como posso fazer isso?

Código do `for`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < texto.size(); i++) {
        String[] aux = texto.get(i).split(" ");

        if (aux.length > 2) {
            cont = 0;

            if (pratos.size() != 0) {
                System.out.println("ta diferente: " + pratos.size());
                objeto.setPratosPossiveis(pratos);
                System.out.println("um pratro add: ");

                casos.add(objeto); //PROBLEMA: ta recebendo sempre o edenreço de objeto e mudando tudo

                System.out.println(casos.get(0).getPratosPossiveis().get(0).get(0));


                pratos.clear();
            }

            objeto = new CasosPossiveis();
            System.out.println("NumerO2: "+objeto.getNumeroDias());
            objeto.setNumeroDias(Integer.parseInt(aux[0]));
            objeto.setNumeroPratos(Integer.parseInt(aux[1]));
            objeto.setOrcamento(Integer.parseInt(aux[2]));

        } else {
            pratos.add(new LinkedList<>());
            pratos.add(new LinkedList<>());
            System.out.println("Valor do cont: " + cont);
            pratos.get(cont).add(Integer.parseInt(aux[0]));
            pratos.get(cont).add(Integer.parseInt(aux[1]));
            System.out.println("o que adicionei 1: " + pratos.get(cont).get(0));
            System.out.println("o que adicionei 2: " + pratos.get(cont).get(1));
            cont++;
        }
    }
  }
    System.out.println("tamanho q ficou: " + casos.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < casos.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("aqui: " + casos.get(i).getPratosPossiveis().size());
        for (int j = 0; j < casos.get(i).getPratosPossiveis().size(); j++) {
            System.out.println("ue");
            System.out.println(casos.get(i).getPratosPossiveis().get(i));
        }

    }
```

Explicação: `texto.size()` tem dados de um arquivo. Cada posição é uma linha do arquivo. Se a linha tiver mais que dois `int`s, eu adiciono o que eu tinha no objeto no meu `ArrayList` de objetos, "limpo" o objeto e começo a adicionar valores novamente no objeto, até eu encontrar uma nova linha com mais e dois `int`s.

Comment: A construção do objeto tem de vir dentro do `for` para que sejam todos diferentes, caso contrário está a adicionar o mesmo objeto em todas as casas do array

Comment: Em Java, todos os objetos são passados por referência. Se você quer colocar um objeto diferente dentro da lista, deve criar um objeto novo, e não colocar novamente o já existente.

Comment: Antes de modificar os valores de objeto, dentro do for, eu faço um ` objeto = new CasosPossiveis();` sempre. Mesmo assim, não está funcionando.

Comment: Então poste o código do seu `for` para entendermos melhor o que acontece.

Comment: Pergunta editada com o código.

Comment: `texto` é do tipo `List<String[]>`?

Comment: Isso. Texto um arraylist de strings. Exemplo da posiçao 0 do texto: 1 3 26. Da posicao 1: 44 5843.

Comment: O que é `pratos`? Acho que esse `objeto.setPratosPossiveis(pratos);` vai fazer todos os `CasosPossiveis` terem a mesma lista de pratos ao invés de dar uma lista de pratos diferentes paara cada um.

Comment: O seu `System.out.println(casos.get(0).getPratosPossiveis().get(0).get(0));` vai sempre pegar o primeiro caso. Talvez devesse ser `System.out.println(objeto.getPratosPossiveis().get(0).get(0));`?

Comment: Pratos é uma matriz que faz parte do meu objeto. Quando a linha tem tamanho maior que 2, eu salvo os dados dela. Quando tem tamanho 2, eu pego os dados da linha e salvo na matriz. Cada linha é uma posição da matriz. As vezes temos 3 ou 4 linhas seguidas de tamanho 2 sem que venha uma nova de tamanho 3. Quando vem, eu limpo o objeto e começo tudo de novo.

Comment: Esse sout era só pra teste, pra ver o que estava pegando na primeira posição. Não é esse o problema não.  Vou editar o código pra lhe mostrar como estou printando os valores e vendo o erro.

Comment: Ao invés de `pratos.clear();`, não seria o caso de fazer um `pratos = new ArrayList<>();`? Acho que não tem sentido destruir a lista que você acabou de adicionar ao `objeto` e nem ter todos eles compartilhando a mesma lista destruída.

Comment: Ou seja, `pratos` é uma matriz de números com duas colunas e várias linhas?

Comment: LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> pratos = new LinkedList<>();

Comment: Cara, acho que consigo resolver o problema da forma que tu disse. Utilizando `pratos = new ArrayList<>();`. Além disso, refiz muita coisa no meu for para ficar mais claro. Estou lendo a lista texto de forma diferente. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: No último `System.out.println`, você está usando `i` duas vezes ao invés de `i` e `j`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mude o tipo de `pratos` para `List<List<Integer>>`. Tente fazer isso:

```
    for (String linha : texto) {
        String[] aux = linha.split(" ");

        if (aux.length > 2) {
            objeto = new CasosPossiveis();
            System.out.println("Numero 2: " + objeto.getNumeroDias());
            objeto.setNumeroDias(Integer.parseInt(aux[0]));
            objeto.setNumeroPratos(Integer.parseInt(aux[1]));
            objeto.setOrcamento(Integer.parseInt(aux[2]));
            pratos = new ArrayList<>();
            objeto.setPratosPossiveis(pratos);
            casos.add(objeto);
        } else {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(aux[0]);
            int b = Integer.parseInt(aux[1]);
            List<Integer> linhaPratos = Arrays.asList(a, b);
            pratos.add(linhaPratos);
        }
    }
}

System.out.println("Tamanho que ficou: " + casos.size());
for (CasosPossiveis caso : casos) {
    System.out.println("aqui: " + caso.getPratosPossiveis().size());
    for (List<Integer> pratosPossiveis : caso.getPratosPossiveis()) {
        System.out.println("ue");
        System.out.println(pratosPossiveis);
    }
}
```

No último `System.out.println`, você estava usando `i` duas vezes ao invés de `i` e `j`. Entretanto, usando a sintaxe do *enhanced-for* fica muito mais fácil de percorrer-se a lista e evitar ter que usar esse monte de índices.

A variável `cont` pode ser eliminada.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Com certeza aprenderei a utilizar enhanced-for. Muito obrigado. PS.: é int b = Integer.parseInt(aux[1]); haha

Comment: @Marcos Editado.